# Struggling with basic experiment printing to stdio

Tags: haskell

Brand new to Haskell and failing to print the date in a simple program.  What I'm trying to do:

1. Get the current time from getCurrentTime
2. Call a pure function on the date, returning a string
3. Print the string to stdio.

I've learned that getCurrentTime returns an IO monad.  I must raise my pure function into the monad using extra sauce like fmap.  Still no luck.

What am I doing wrong?

--- EDIT ---

Forgot to mention that this compiles and runs but produces no output.

```
module Main where
import System.IO
import Data.Time.Clock
import Data.Time.Calendar

date :: IO (Integer,Int,Int)
date = fmap (toGregorian . utctDay) getCurrentTime

getDateStr :: (Integer,Int,Int) -> String
getDateStr (year,month,day) = "Date is " ++ show year ++ "/" ++ show month ++ "/" ++ show day ++ "\n"

main = do
    let printabledate = fmap getDateStr date
    fmap print printabledate
```

Comment: You should include the error in your question. Anyway, `fmap print printabledate` will get you an `IO (IO ())`. You could use `printabledate >>= print`, but it’s more common to make use of that `do` and `printabledate <- date` then `printStrLn $ getDateStr date`.

Comment: `main = print =<< getDateStr <$> date`

Comment: @Ryan - Oops yes, I updated the question to describe the non-result.  Your >>= suggestion worked, though I don't yet understand why.  Care to leave an answer?

Comment: `fmap print :: Show a => IO a -> IO (IO ())` is a function which given an `IO` action producing a value of some type `a`, gives another `IO` action which, when executed, has no side effects and produces yet another `IO` action - that last one is the one which prints the input. In other words, executing an `IO (IO ())` doesn't execute the inner `IO` action, only the outer one. (This is a duplicate of any number of questions, but I'm too lazy to find any of them)

Comment: I recommend giving `main` the explicit type signature `main :: IO ()` (here and in the future), to avoid this sort of thing.

Comment: @Ryan you probably mean `putStrLn` rather than `printStrLn`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's forget the concept of monads for a second to clear stuff a bit:

In OOP, we have classes. Most of the time, these bind some behaviour to some data. In Haskell we do not do this, and rather we create **data types** that are just that, data.

Also, in OOP, we have the concept of **interface**, which allows us to define an API for some common functions that some classes can share. In some way, we could group those classes by properties they share, like for example creating an interface `Mappable` which has a `map` method that applies a function to the contents of the class that implements that interface.

Now, for example we could create a class `List<T>` that implements `Mappable` where `map` applies the function to each of the elements of the list.

In Haskell, we have **type classes** which are like interfaces, but much better, because they allow you to implement the API for any existing type. For example our `Mappable` from before, is called `Functor` in Haskell. Don't get scared, as it is just a name like `AbstractEnterpriseJavaBeanFactory`. It is defined like this:

```
class Functor f where
    fmap :: (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
    ...
```

And now we can extend anything that has some contents, like our `List<T>` from before, with it, which in Haskell would be:

```
data List a = ...    -- List implementation

instance Functor List where
    fmap f lst = ...     -- Implementation of fmap
```

This is great, because the `Functor` concept gives us the assurance that the function `f` will be applied to the contents of the data types that implements this, always returning another copy of the data type.

And you now might be wondering, what has this to do with my question?

Haskell comes with a lot of predefined type classes: `Functor`, `Foldable`, `Applicative`, ...

Type classes only assure you that some constraints will be met when applying the functions defined in their API:

- Functor's `fmap` takes a function `a -> b` and an `f a` as argument
- Applicative takes a "container" with a function inside `f (a -> b)` and an `f a`
- etc...

Within all these many typeclasses there is one that has the following API

```
class X f where
    bind :: (a -> f b) -> f a -> f b
```

It's like our functor from before, but instead of returning an element, the function passed as a parameter, returns another "container".

**This typeclass is called Monad**, and in Haskell it is defined like:

```
class Monad m where
    (>>=) :: m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b
    return :: a -> m a    -- This puts the value a inside of the "container" m
    ...
```

*(Note that arguments are flipped)*

So basically *IO* is not a monad, just a container type that happens to implement the API defined in the type class `Monad`, but also `Functor` and many others (you can check them in the *instances* section of [the IO API documentation](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.6.0.1/docs/System-IO.html#t:IO)).

Now let's reason a bit:

First of all, we use `date` to get an `IO (Integer, Int, Int)`, which basically is a container that contains the triple.

Then, we apply the `getDateStr` function to it's contents using `fmap`, so we get back an `IO` that has `String` inside of it.

Now we bind this value to `printableDate`. So `printableDate` is now an `IO String`.

Now we apply `print` to the contents of `printableDate` using `fmap`, but wait, `print` returns an "empty" `IO` container, so now what we get back is an `IO` containing an `IO ()` ( `IO (IO ())` ), but the `main` function's return type must be always `IO ()`.

What do we do now? We have two options:

**1)** Unwrap the value inside our `printableDate` using the `<-` operator, allowing us to get the `String` itself:

```
main = do
    let printabledate = fmap getDateStr date
    unwrappedPrintableDate <- printabledate
    print unwrappedPrintabledate
```

Or, directly:

```
main = do
    printabledate <- fmap getDateStr date
    print printabledate
```

**2)** Use the `>>=` operator defined in the `Monad` type class:

```
main = do
    let printabledate = fmap getDateStr date
    printabledate >>= print
```

Remember? The `>>=` operator expects that the function passed to it returns another "container", which is what `print` does.

Use which one feels more natural to you, as they are both accepted and [the same thing](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/do_notation)

Answer (score 2):

It works like this:

- `fmap :: (a -> b) -> f a -> f b`, noted the function to `fmap` is a normal function.
- `fmap getDateStr date :: IO String`.
- `print :: a -> IO ()`, `a` will be `String`.

So: `fmap print (fmap getDateStr date)` will has type of `IO (IO ())`. The point is `print` is **not** a "normal" function, but it is a **monadic** function. You `fmap` a monadic function to a monadic value, you will get a monadic value wrapped inside another monadic value.

Then, when you evaluate `main`, you get back the inner monadic value of type `IO ()`. That's not what you want. To get the desired result, just `bind` `print` to `printabledate` as @Ryan suggested in the comment:

```
    (>>=) :: m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b
    printabledate >>= print :: IO ()
```

That's all.